# AsyncTask For Setting Image Views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask, android-imageview

So i've been trying to use methods like `runOnUiThread()` and View.

post to update my image views from a class that is outside of the main one which **does not extend Activity** and I keep getting the same problem:

the first time it runs great but when I relaunch the application, the image views won't update anymore.

Can I use the `AsyncTask` class to take in a bitmap and then use that bitmap to set and Image view to it? If so, can anyone show me an example?

Comment: AsyncTask has no reference to the Main UI thread outside of onPreExecute() and onPostExecute(). You would have to do some work arounds to get that to happen without AsyncTask throwing an exception during the doInBackground() method execution, which does the actual work.

Answer (score 2):

If you extends the AsyncTask like this

class ClassName extends AsyncTask

You'll have to return a Bitmap from the doInBackground(), and you'll be override onPostExecute(Bitmap), which will run on the UI thread which means you'll be able to set that Bitmap to an ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

Only the `runInBackground()` method of the AsyncTasks is invoked on a `worker thread`. The other methods are invoked on the UI Thread, so you can use that to call changes to your UI.

You can use `onPreExecute()` for like a progress bar to start with.

You can use `publishProgress()`, as it says, publish progresses of your task, like saying how much percent you have downloaded.

You can use `onPostExecute()` to set your Views , like bitmaps or pieces of text you might have downloaded.